# Add Notes/Annotations to Morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

Looking to add annotations to my implementation of morris.js charts. Is there any way to do this? I cannot see it on their website?

I need to add notes to specific dates.

Comment: do you mean `labels` for `xkey` and `ykeys` or something else?

Comment: something else, Looking for Google Analytics style, I have dates that I want to add a vertical line to show or an icon under date on the x axis. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have such possibility, according to their [documentation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)

All you can do is to define `labels` for `xkey` and `ykeys`.

But it shouldn't be a problem at all, to add the text legend next to your chart with html and simple JS snippet. So I don't see any difficulties here, just add another `div` with the text you need.